# How to change color of the UINavigationBar & buttons on it?

Tags: iphone

I want to change color of the UINavigationBar?

Is it possible to keep different colors of UINavigationBar & buttons on it?

Comment: Please change the selected answer to the one with a higher rating as the on selected now it not correct.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can only set style of navigation bar. Default or black. Also you can set black and set translucent to YES to get blackTranslucent bar.

Comment: Correct, setting the tintColor is what you will want to do. You can set it with a value created with UIColor with the initWithRed:green:blue:alpha: constructor. Or you can create a view connected with an IBOutlet and use the backgroundColor property of that view to set the color or the UINavigationBar. I like this approach better because it allows me to visually adjust the color in the NIB. I can also keep a few color samples around for reference.

Answer (score 21):

UINavigationBar has a `tintColor` property for this.

Comment: This doesn't seems working for me. when i apply tintColor property my Navigationbar of UITableViewController changes to only white color. Actually i am setting orange color for NavigationBar. What is the problem?

Comment: `navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];` doesn't work?