# Adding colour to uinavigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

How to add colour to the `navigation bar` ? I need to implement this for `iOS 4` and above.

I want a colour similar to the one in the screenshot:

[image: App Screenshot with magenta-ish UINavigationBar color]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change color of the UINavigationBar & buttons on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636794/how-to-change-color-of-the-uinavigationbar-buttons-on-it) ... Ignore the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: You can have one code path for 4 and one for 5 but don't switch on OS version.  Test with respondsToSelector.  See related post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5/7801253#7801253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS < 5 you can set tint color of individual navigation bar directly, e.g.:

```
// self is a UIViewController
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Once you don't need compatibility with iOS 4.x you can use appearance proxy for `UINavigationBar`. This would work for all navigation bars in the application:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Comment: If i only use the iOS 4 code will it work for both iOS 4 and 5 ?

Comment: The first works for both iOS 4 and 5, the only downside is that having more than one navbar in the application you'd have to set the color for each one of them separately.

Comment: You can also test and switch via respondsToSelector.  See a related example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5/7801253#7801253

Answer (score 2):

In the example you posted, It looks more like a backround image because of the slight lighting effect. (It's brighter in the middle, it you look closely. In IB, I have the nav bar set to Black Transparent with the following Background Image. (320 x 44px)

h file.

```
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

m file "viewDidLoad" function:

```
navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav"]];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, i was expecting something like yours, but how did you get that tiny space between the `Nav Bar` and `time - the small bar where it shows the battery life etc` ?

Comment: Actually, thanks for noticing that. It's an image view in my mainViewController. The wood is supposed to go all the way to the top behind the status bar, so I need to fix that, but when setting the dimensions for the image view, I simply made the UIImageView a full 320x480 and then set the x to 160 (center) and the y to 220 instead of 240, which pushes it up behind the status bar. The status bar is a 20px tall and even if you "Fill Container Vertically, you still have to move it up manually, I've discovered.

Comment: How did you make the UIButton blue colour ? i think you might have used a image there. I tried adding an image from IB but it ended up giving a white box and not the image it self. So could you tell the correct way of adding an image through IB ?